# How to use django together with mongoengine?

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I want to use a mongodb database together with the django framework. For that purpose I tried to set up a small test project using the mongoengine and this description: http://staltz.com/djangoconfi-mongoengine/#/8

Unfortunately, it is not working. The relevant parts of my settings.py, views.py and models.py are looking like this:

settings.py:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
import mongoengine

[...]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'testApp',
)
[...]

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': '',
    }
}

SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'

_MONGODB_USER = 'mongouser'
_MONGODB_PASSWD = 'test'
_MONGODB_HOST = 'localhost'
_MONGODB_NAME = 'testDb'
_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST = \
  'mongodb://%s:%s@%s/%s' \
  % (_MONGODB_USER, _MONGODB_PASSWD, _MONGODB_HOST, _MONGODB_NAME)

mongoengine.connect(_MONGODB_NAME, host=_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',
)
```

models.py

```
from mongoengine import *

# Create your models here.
class Choice(Document):
  choice_text = StringField(max_length=200)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from testApp.models import Choice
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

def index(request):
  newChoice = Choice(choice_text="First test")
  newChoice.save()
  return HttpResponse("Test")

user = authenticate(username='mongouser', password='test')
assert isinstance(user, mongoengine.django.auth.User)
```

When I start the testserver and open the testApp website, I get an "ImportError: No module named django.sessions". Therefore, I removed the SESSION_ENGINE part from my settings.py, which was marked as optional in above's description. Afterwards I get an "No module named django.auth" error.

Do you have an idea what is going wrong and how to set up django together with mongoengine in order to use a mongodb database?

Comment: Which version of Django, mongoengine  and pymongo you are using?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I didn't have access to the machine over the weekend:

Django 1.8.2
mongoengine 0.10.0
pymongo 3.0.2

But actually I don't use pymongo.

Comment: can you tell me from where do you find _MONGODB_PASSWD and _MONGODB_USER ? @rahul-gupta

Comment: @AdarshTiwari This is your MongoDB username and password.

Answer (score 4):

this is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32451941/importerror-no-module-named-django-sessions). with mongoengine 0.10 we can see that  /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/ will not have django package in it. Install mongoengine 0.9 using sudo pip install mongoengine==0.9 and the django package (support or extension) will be available.

Answer (score 1):

**I want to use a mongodb database together with the django framework**

If this is your goal there are several ways to accomplish it. Depending on the strategy you take, do factor in the trade offs.

**Use a MongoDB compatible model framework (MongoEngine):** You can completely avoid using the Django models in your project and use MongoEngine or Ming in you django projects. However will miss out on: [1500+ core contributors](https://dashboard.djangoproject.com/) to the project, hourly fixes and ticket resolution, ramp down on the expertise of existing Django models and ramp up on the new model framework. Miss out on Django’s contrib models like Admin, Sessions, Users, Auth, etc., contrib modules for your project.

**Django SQL to MongoDB transpiler — [Djongo](http://nesdis.github.io/djongo/):** Translate Django SQL query syntax generated by the Django ORM into pymongo commands. Djongo is one such SQL to MongoDB query compiler. It translates every SQL query string into a mongoDB query document. As a result, all Django models and related modules work as is.

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue with using the latest version of `pymongo` with Django.

Try downgrading `pymongo` to 2.8 and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Define envs in .env file for database connection:

```
DB_NAME=mock
DB_USER=test
DB_PASS=secret
HOST=localhost
```

In app/settings.py:

```
import mongoengine

# Load envs
import environ
env = environ.Env()
env.read_env(env.str('ENV_PATH', '../.env'))
mongoengine.connect(db=env('DB_NAME'), host=env('HOST'), username=env('DB_USER'), password=env('DB_PASS'),serverSelectionTimeoutMS=1000)
DATABASES = {
     'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
     },
}


TEST_RUNNER = 'app.tests.NoSQLTestRunner'
```

In app/tests:

```
class NoSQLTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def __init__(self, mocking, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def setup_databases(self, **kwargs):
        pass

    def teardown_databases(self, old_config, **kwargs):
        pass

    def setup_test_environment(self, **kwargs):
        super(NoSQLTestRunner, self).setup_test_environment(**kwargs)

class NoSQLTestCase(TestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NoSQLTestCase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        disconnect()
        connect('mongoenginetest', host='mongomock://localhost')

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        disconnect()

    def _fixture_setup(self):
        pass

    def _fixture_teardown(self):
        pass
```

Now you can create models as represented in mongoengine docs, and write tests:

```
from app.tests import NoSQLTestCase
from myapp.models import MyModel

class CustodianOrganizationTest(NoSQLTestCase):
    def test_my_testcase(self)
        instance = MyModel()
        instance.save()
        assumed = "Foo"
        self.assertEqual(instance.foo, assumed)
   ...
```

and run tests by `python3 manage.py test`

This setup is tested running succesfully with:

```
python 3.9
Django 3.1.3
mongoengine 0.22.0
pymongo 3.11.2
```